# Apache directory listing permissions by user

Tags: apache

I have Apache HTTP Server 4.4.9 running on Windows computer.
There are 2 users, administrator and john.

Administrator should have access to c:\HTTP Storage and all subfolders, with enabled directory listings.
User john should have access only to folder c:\HTTP Storage\john and all subfolders, with disabled directory listings.

Problem is that my configuration doesn't allow user administrator the directory listing in folder c:\HTTP Storage\john, only c:\HTTP Storage\

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Order deny,allow
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/HTTP Storage">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/htpasswd"
Require user administrator
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/HTTP Storage/john">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/htpasswd"
Require user administrator john
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to the above?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I found a small utility tool called *accesschk* on Windows that lists the read and write permissions of a user on a folder and its elements. So eventually I used an LDAP authentication mechanism to identify the user and check their password against Active Directory. Using that tool, I then wrote a small Python script that checks what rights the user has on the current directory and display its elements programmatically. HTH.